# Bayes factors and predictive accuracy in model comparison in rstan / brms

Tags: cross-validation, interaction, model-comparison, bayes-factors, waic

Despite reading up on the subject, I can't wrap my head round it, so the question remains on shaky grounds, and responses along the lines of "read chapter x" are very welcome.

What I'm **doing** is I'm fitting models predicting binary responses using two ordered factors A and B as predictors. I want to tell how much evidence I have that A and B interact (the effect of A gets stronger across the various levels of B).

I fit the models in `brms`. I assume flat priors (because I have no assumptions, because I came over from frequentist model fitting, and because priors are scary) and a bernoulli error distribution and a logit link function.

**First**, I fit *model A* `response ~ A + B` and *model B* `response ~ A * B`.

**Second**, I compare the models using WAIC and ten-fold cross-validation (using `loo_compare`).

Both these comparisons suggest that the predictive accuracy of *model A* is better than that of B  -- or, in some cases, that it is not worse. (the elpd difference suggests better elpd for *model A* or the se of the difference eats the difference itself)

Given worse predictive accuracy for *model B*, I'd pick *model A* (and give up on the interaction).

Given no difference in predictive accuracy, I'm inclined to pick *model A* again, the model with no interaction, on account of parsimony.

**Third**, I ask: is *model A* a better fit because the data provide evidence for H0 (no ineraction) over H1 (interaction) or merely because they don't provide enough data to exclude H0?

I calculate Bayes factors (using `bayes_factor(*model A*,*model B*)`, repeatedly, to see variance).

I **expect** one of two outcomes: BF will be 1< and high (meaning that *model A* is much more likely than *model B*). Or: BF will be ~1 (meaning that the two models are equally likely).

My **result** is that Bayes Factors **prefer** [edited] *model B* (with the interaction) to a massive degree.

I'd like to know how to interpret the conflicting evidence from predictive accuracy and Bayes Factors. It is entirely possible that *picking* a model is not the way to go.

If the result follows from a common mistake, I'd like to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the quizzical, this might be the way to go:

"The problem with your Bayes factor is that brms uses improper flat priors for regression coefficients by default. These priors should not be used with Bayes factors. Thus, you need to set reasonable and proper priors on these coefficients."

see: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/bayes-factors-in-brms/4109

Answer (score 2):

Without more details, I can't speak about the specifics of this problem, but generally one should note that the ML that goes into BF is essentially the average likelihood over the prior, i.e. it is HIGHLY prior-dependent. WAIC and CV are calculated over the fitted model, and are thus approximately prior-independent, assuming that you have reasonably strong data.

Differences between BF and WAIC are therefore built-in when using arbitrary (in particular wide) priors. Logically, however, this is undesirable, as we would like to have consistent model selection. The basic solution to this is that you shouldn't use the BF on uncalibrated priors. Because you don't want to use your data twice, one option is to split the data and calibrate with one part, and calculate the BF on the hold-out (O'Hagan, Anthony. "Fractional Bayes factors for model comparison." Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Methodological) 57, no. 1 (1995): 99-118.). If you do this, results should be roughly consistent with WAIC and CV.

For your specific case, I would further note that wide (or even inproper) priors usually favor the simpler model disproportionally when calculating the BF, so it is somewhat surprising that your BF favors model B stronger than WAIC with flat priors. This is a behavior that I would expect with narrow priors. Are you sure you have wide priors?